# Is there any way to make a tag in XSLT as optional?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

```
<xsl:attribute name="ACTIVATE_FIRST_MODEL_VIEW">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ACTIVATE_FIRST_MODEL_VIEW='X'">true</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="ACTIVATE_FIRST_MODEL_VIEW=''">false</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>

<xsl:attribute name="VARIANT" use-attribute-sets="OPTIONAL">
    <xsl:value-of select="VARIANT"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Here i want the tag with attribute name="VARIANT" to be optional. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "optional"? Optional to whom?

Comment: BTW `use-attribute-sets` is not a valid attribute of `xsl:attribute`. See [W3.org: 7.1.4 Named Attribute Sets](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-sets).

Answer (score 0):

*If* you mean it to be only copied to the output if present, don't use `xsl:attribute>` at all:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@VARIANT"/>
```

Otherwise it's unclear what you're asking, and specifically 'the tag with attribute name="VARIANT"' is meaningless.

Comment: that was a mistake in the code when i copied it. It is not required

Comment: What was a mistake, and how does the mistake relate to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is putting the creation of the attribute in `<xsl:if>` like this:

```
<xsl:if test="VARIANT != ''">
  <xsl:attribute name="VARIANT" use-attribute-sets="OPTIONAL">
    <xsl:value-of select="VARIANT"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

This only creates the attribute if it's not empty.

Comment: This didn't work. But worked when i i gave the expression test=''VARIANT!='' "

Comment: Yes, that may (have) be(en) the case. I updated the answer with your suggestion, a more specific approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to create the attribute VARIANT in the output if and only if there is an attribute VARIANT in the input, just use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@VARIANT"/>
```

By the way, I don't know what you think a "tag" is, but you're using the term incorrectly and that's one of the things that makes your post confusing. The other thing that makes it confusing is that you have given us no clue what your input looks like or what you want your output to look like.